# Косный и косТный: разница

Tags: этимология

"Костный" — состоящий из костей, имеющий костную основу. Косный — застойный, неразвивающийся. В принципе, где-то понятия перекликаются. Но есть ли между ними что-то общее, или слово "косный" произошло от слова "касаться" (что не логично)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет. Кость-древнеслав., развилось из др.-р."кость" - останки, связанное с битвой.
Косный-заимствовано из ст.-сл.-медленный, нерадивый, отсталый.
Касаться, коснуться- и в др.-р, и в ст.-слав.- от *kes-чесать, скрести, трогать.
Так что совершенно разные слова, не перекликаются ни в чём.

Answer (score 1):

Разве только в созвучности сходство.